# HTML Form posting twice to php script

Tags: php, html, forms, apache2

I know this has been brought up before, but I can't find any actual explanation to it, so I was hoping with a bit more information, we could put this to rest.

**The Issue:** When a user submits the html form, the browser posts the info to a php script - it should only do this once, but I can see it is doing it twice.

Here is the apache2 log entry that proves it:

```
192.168.178.20 - - [22/Jul/2014:15:00:14 +0000] "POST /postman/scripts/run.php HTTP/1.1" 302 325 "http://192.168.178.33/postman/submit.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) $
192.168.178.20 - - [22/Jul/2014:15:00:16 +0000] "POST /postman/scripts/run.php HTTP/1.1" 302 326 "http://192.168.178.33/postman/submit.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) $
```

You can see the form was posted twice within 2 seconds. I was standing right behind the user, she didn't refresh the page, or click back and resend.

Here's the long winded background for anyone who wants to tackle this.

The website is hosted on a Raspberry Pi, and is only accessible from one pc within the local network. It only hosts one site which is a program I am developing that allows the user to send an email to multiple people (to put it very simply).

The user launches the site on their desktop, and basically fills in the html form with certain information, like the email body, the subject and which group to send to etc...

The html form posts to a php script which is only responsible for writing the information to txt files, and then executing the bash script which is loops the email sending over the group of recipients.

It's all fairly simple, but if the html form posts twice, basically the entire program comes crumbling down and leaves me looking like an idiot. Maybe I am...

I can figure a way to stop this from happening again, but I would really like to know what I did wrong. I am hoping there is a simple explanation for this...

Thanks.
Tim

EDIT:

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="post" action="./scripts/run.php" align="right" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" align="right" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ob_start();
exec('./postman.sh');
header('Location: /postman/verify.html');
exit;
?>
```

Apologies, the above is the correct form and script...

Comment: Where's the code? We are not psychics :)

Comment: BTW: This only started happening yesterday - no changes were made to any of the code involved prior to this. It used to run perfectly fine, no hitches...

Comment: mdesdev, which code would you need to see? It's a really basic html form...

Comment: the php script, and html @asimovwasright

Comment: HTML, PHP, JS but if you're saying that everything worked fine till yesterday...maybe is something wrong with server.

Comment: OK, there are the codes. Probably doesn't need to be said, but php is NOT my strong suit. And the html form was written ages ago.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong form. It was actually the submit button that was posted twice. - I have edited the post now.

Comment: OMG!! I'm the biggest idiot who ever lived... I am really sorry for wasting your time @mdesdev & Janne Klouman

Once the user clicks on the submit button, the page does not change until the shell script has completed, and then the php scripts sends the header location.. 

The user could easily click on the submit button twice... ( hangs head in shame ) :-(

So sorry...

Comment: No biggie, it's important that you found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer was to create a js function to replace the html button with something else immediately after being clicked, so the user is not able to click twice while waiting. I used a generic loading gif, all worked fine...